# REST WebApi username/password security

Tags: rest, http-headers, asp.net-web-api, basic-authentication

I am designing a series of web services using the new microsoft asp.net mvc 4 WebApi.

For any call to any of these services a username and password must be passed each time  and these details must be checked in sql server to authorize the user.

Questions:

1) Would it be correct to pass the username and password each time using the basic authentication headers or perhaps custom http headers? The thing is I don't want to interfere with the querystring or the request body in each call and would prefer headers.

2) Once passed in headers how can I use the authorize attribute to to call my method that verifies the user is valid in sql? Do I need to roll a custom authorize attribute?

Comment: I saw today, with luck [this link](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/376810/ASP-NET-WEB-API-Custom-Authorize-and-Exception-Han)

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, provided it's over HTTPS - Take a look here at writing your own message handler, http://sixgun.wordpress.com/2012/02/29/asp-net-web-api-basic-authentication/

Answer (score 1):

There are a few implementations already there, best being Dominick's Baier:

http://leastprivilege.com/2012/05/26/thinktecture-identitymodel-and-asp-net-web-api/

This one is using attributes:

http://www.piotrwalat.net/basic-http-authentication-in-asp-net-web-api-using-membership-provider/

Comment: all above links are sending the password using base64 encryption, if in browser we can see base64 string cannot anyone decode the base64 string to normal text?